# click Button event not firing in android while saving image

Tags: android

I am implementing an camera application.When a click on the get image its does not work.No further action in performed on the button.Can anyone tell where's is the problem ??

Answer (score 2):

Hello friend
You want to implement your whole application in 
mobile device not virtual device.
So for that you have to install your app in your android mobile
and than check.
May be this reason you get an error.

Just check once.

Comment: Hey pintu,,,,should i paste the code here....Its not working....Here there is no option of uploading a file,,,Whats ur email id.I will send u on ur id...

Comment: If you have android mobile then try there. It's working in your mobile rather than your emulator. Just check it